# How can I build a page that generates random images from a gallery each time the page is refreshed?

Tags: html, css, random, gallery

Pardon my complete n00bness as I try to figure this out:

I run a daily cartoon/drawing website. I'm not a developer so I'm using the site builder called Pixpa which has worked well for my straightforward needs: daily update on homepage + archival galleries.

There is one thing I would like to implement that the site builder is not equipped for. I would like to have a page called "random cartoon" that, when visited, populates with a random cartoon from the archive.

I can create a basic page using the site builder and it has the option to add HTML to customize. Theoretically, I figure this means I could create this "random cartoon" page from scratch, but I don't know where to start.

One other note that may be an issue - the image files for the cartoon are not located in any one central folder/volume in the backend of the website. Pixpa does not have that function. So right now each cartoon exists on the site in a corresponding gallery and has been assigned a url such as "https://s3-img.pixpa.com/com/800/636137/1647641530-19265-guy-631-february-14-2022.jpeg"

There are almost 700 cartoons so far, with more being added each and every day, so this is a major aspect of my issue...

In summation my question is - how and where should I organize my images so that I can implement this "random cartoon" page most efficiently, and once I have completed that organization, what CSS should I use to create the functional page?

Appreciate any insights you may have. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use JavaScript too, you could import your images, add them all to an `const imageList = []`, then chose a random one using a random number generator.

Answer (score 0):

As Harley suggested with some Javascript you can create an array of images and then invoke the Math.random() method to obtain a random number that would grab the corresponding image in the array and display it. Maybe some CSS wizard can chime in with a pure CSS method if that's possible.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Still in over my head here, but will seek more info....